# How to put the "Display Name" in a label on a Blazor page?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

I have the following model:

```cs
class User
{
    [Display(Name = "Display Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In standard Razor I would do something like the following to get the "Display Name":

```
<label asp-for="Model.Name"></label>
```

but that doesn't seem to work in Blazor. Does anyone know how to get the display name in a Blazor page without using reflection?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18016

Answer (score 18):

My implementation is to replace the `Html.DisplayNameFor()` method from regular Razor;

```
@using System.Reflection
@using System.Linq.Expressions;
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
@typeparam T
@if (ChildContent == null)
{
    <label>@label</label>
}
else
{
    <label>
        @label
        @ChildContent
    </label>
}
@code {
    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<T>> For { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    private string label => GetDisplayName();

    private string GetDisplayName()
    {
        var expression = (MemberExpression)For.Body;
        var value = expression.Member.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DisplayAttribute)) as DisplayAttribute;
        return value?.Name ?? expression.Member.Name ?? "";
    }
}
```

with this at the call site, either:

```
<DisplayName For="@(() => object.Member)" />
```

or

```
<DisplayName For="@(() => object.Member)">
    <InputText @bind-Value="object.Member" />
</DisplayName>
```

**Edit:** to clarify, the two versions produce slightly different markup. The first would produce:

```
<label>Generated DisplayName</label>
```

And the second would produce

```
<label>
    Generated DisplayName
    <input value="WhateverTheValueIs" />
</label>
```

Additionally, in my implementation I added a `bool` property to allow just plaintext output - since it turned out there was lots of times I just wanted the display name text out.

Comment: I've tried this solution and it works but I'm not sure what the ChildContent is for?

Comment: The two calls produce slightly different markup. The first just gives a label with the display name in it. `<label>DisplayName</label>` and the second gives the same, but with any additional child content presented in the component tag, which is a regular way to put an `input` inside a `label`. I'll edit the answer to show what would get generated.

Comment: A lot of similar examples, but to get them to work in 2021 I had to simplify the Parameter to just: <LabelSmart For="() => object.Member" />    Without the extra @ and ()

Comment: I changed your `GetDisplayName()` method a bit to work with Resource files too. `return value?.Name ...` to `return value?.GetName() ...`

Answer (score 16):

@BlackFenix2 I'm not allowed to comment (yet ) but `<Label For="@(() => Model.Name))" />` should be `<Label For="@(() => Model.Name)" />` *One ')' to many*

And to enhance your solution somewhat I've added `@attributes="AdditionalAttributes"` so you can do this (*for example*) `<Label class="col-3 col-form-label" For="@(() => Model.Name)" />`

```
@using System.Reflection
@using System.ComponentModel
@using System.Linq.Expressions;

<label @attributes="AdditionalAttributes">@label</label>

@code {
    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<string>> For { get; set; }

    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
    public IDictionary<string, object> AdditionalAttributes { get; set; }

    private string label => GetDisplayName();

    private string GetDisplayName()
    {
        var expression = (MemberExpression)For.Body;
        var value = expression.Member.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute)) as DisplayNameAttribute;
        return value?.DisplayName ?? expression.Member.Name ?? "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

#### Bad news:

At this time (preview7), they are not an out of the box feature to do it.

#### Good news:

It's very easy to create your own custom label component (using a bit reflection of course) and encapsulate functionality in it:

```
@using System.Linq
@using System.Reflection
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

@typeparam TItem

<label for="@fortag">@label</label>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string aspfor { get; set; }        

    private string label => GetDisplayName(aspfor);

    private string fortag => aspfor;

    private string GetDisplayName(string propertyname)
    {
        MemberInfo myprop = typeof(TItem).GetProperty(propertyname) as MemberInfo;
        var dd = myprop.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DisplayAttribute)) as DisplayAttribute;
        return dd?.Name ?? "";
    }

}
```

And use it in your .razor page:

```
<CustomLabel TItem="User" aspfor="@nameof(User.Name)"></CustomLabel>
```

*Be free to improve it with `Expressions` or more typed code (as [@issac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57204846/842935) explains in their answer) and come back to us to explain your experience.*

#### Demo:

Try it at [blazorfiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/vj4j6zgn).

Comment: Fixed, @BarışAkkurt Thanks for your comment. Can you consider to remove the comment at this time?

Answer (score 7):

I extended the solution from @Kruft to be able to use MetadataType Attribute and have the Display Name in a Resource File maintained using [ResX Manager](https://github.com/tom-englert/ResXResourceManager/wiki). To keep it short I just provided Code snippets :

```
    [MetadataType(typeof(AnforderungDtoMetadata))]
    public partial class AnforderungDto : IMapBaseFrom<Anforderung>
    {

        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public short ReychsNr { get; set; }
        public int SassenNr { get; set; }
        public string AbgerufenVonName { get; set; }
    }
    public class AnforderungDtoMetadata
    {
       [Display(Name = nameof(Resources.AnforderungId), ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
       public object Id { get; set; } 
       [Display(Name = nameof(Resources.ReychsNr), ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
       public object ReychsNr { get; set; }
    }
```

The Blazor Code is the same, I extended only the Methode to get the Display Name:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Reflection;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Resources;
using System.Globalization;

namespace avsweb.Components
{
    public partial class DisplayName<T> : ComponentBase
    {
        [Parameter] public Expression<Func<T>> For { get; set; }
        [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

        private string label => GetDisplayName();

        private string GetDisplayName()
        {
            var expression = (MemberExpression)For.Body;
            var value = expression.Member.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DisplayAttribute), true) as DisplayAttribute;
            if (value == null)
            {
                var metaData = expression.Member.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(MetadataTypeAttribute), true) as MetadataTypeAttribute;
                if (metaData != null)
                {
                    var mdProp = metaData.MetadataClassType.GetProperties()
                             .ToList()
                             .Where(p => p.Name == expression.Member.Name)
                             .FirstOrDefault();
                    if (mdProp != null)
                    {
                        var mPropAttr = mdProp.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DisplayAttribute)) as DisplayAttribute;
                        if (mPropAttr != null)
                        {
                            if (mPropAttr.ResourceType!=null)
                            {
                                return GetDisplayNameFromResource(mPropAttr);
                            }
                            //return mPropAttr.Name;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            if (value.ResourceType!=null)
            {
                return GetDisplayNameFromResource(value);
            }
            return value?.Name ?? expression.Member.Name ?? "";
        }

        private static string GetDisplayNameFromResource(DisplayAttribute mPropAttr)
        {
            ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(mPropAttr.ResourceType);
            var dispName = rm.GetString(mPropAttr.Name, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            return dispName;
        }
```

Bonus: In large Projects its possible to put the Resource File i a common project.

Have fun!

Answer (score 3):

I took a riff at this, i found a way to get the display name of a property passing in an expression like @Issac said. this implementation will work with any custom attribute attached to the property.

and thanks to @dani herrera for the initial code

```cs
 <Label For="@(() => Model.Name))" />
```

```cs
@using System.Linq
@using System.Reflection
@using System.ComponentModel
@using System.Linq.Expressions;

<label>@label</label>

@code {


    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<string>> For { get; set; }

    private string label => GetDisplayName();

    private string GetDisplayName()
    {
        var expression = (MemberExpression)For.Body;
        var value = expression.Member.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute)) as DisplayNameAttribute;
        return value?.DisplayName ?? expression.Member.Name ?? "";
    }

}
```

Comment: This is great, any idea what's involved with handling local variables in the expression instead of member properties?

Comment: I used your solution in my project, but when I passed in an expression of type `DateTime?` it said "no":

`Cannot implicitly convert type System.DateTime to string`

Comment: Added my own answer :)

Answer (score 1):

@user3224222, sorry, but it seems to me that this is not possible right now. I might be mistaken, and this might be easy to set. I'm intrigued by this question, and I'll post it in github to find out how it can be done. However, you may create a component with an embedded label element that can solve your issue. Your component should be similar to the built-in ValidationMessage (https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/4928eb3de0d80570dad93a143b52a8f5a205dac7/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/ValidationMessage.cs) with a property named **For** which can make the trick. This is how the ValidationMessage is set:

```
<ValidationMessage For="@(() => starship.MaximumAccommodation)" />
```

And your component can be similarly set:

```
<LabelText For="@(() => Model.Name))" />
```

Note: You can copy the code of ValidationMessage class as-is and remove all the irrelevant code... You need the For property and the rendering of your component (overriding BuildRenderTree)

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, @dani, for your awesome answer, for the bad news and for the good news. However, the user is looking for a solution that make no use of reflection. Also, I guess that Model is an instance of the User class...thanks.

Comment: Yes, sure in future blazor will have helpers for that.

Comment: @Enet Could you explain to us how to recover the name which is in annotation, because the only thing which I manage to recover and the name of field we use _fieldIdentifier.FieldName