# Equivalent in Blazor for Html.DisplayNameFor() and Html.DisplayFor()

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I have the following ASP.Net code:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => P.coor)
        </div><div class="col-6">

            @Html.DisplayFor(model => P.coor)
        </div>
    </div>
```

P.coor declaration is:

```
[DisplayName("Coordinates")] [StringLength(1000)] public string coor { get; set; }
```

I am trying to get similar functionality in Blazor WASM. Are there equivalents for these Html helpers? What I am especially concerned about is getting the DisplayName attribute value. I am seeing solutions using reflection - is that the best there is?

***Update
Just founf this GitHub issue that seems to mean there is no solution and it will not be added anytime soon. Does anyone know otherwise?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to put the "Display Name" in a label on a Blazor page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57202354/how-to-put-the-display-name-in-a-label-on-a-blazor-page)

Comment: Thank you yes, this is the path I'm trying. I was wandering if there is a native way to do it, seeing as how well it was supported in Razor.

Answer (score 0):

So here is what I've ended up with. It is based on [How to put the "Display Name" in a label on a Blazor page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57202354/how-to-put-the-display-name-in-a-label-on-a-blazor-page), suggested by Dimitris but with some clarifications and updates.

The NameLabel component uses reflection to get the attribute value:

```
@using System.Linq
@using System.Reflection
@using System.ComponentModel
@using System.Linq.Expressions;

<label>@label</label>

@code {


    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<string>> For { get; set; }

    private string label => GetDisplayName();

    private string GetDisplayName()
    {
        var expression = (MemberExpression)For.Body;
        var value = expression.Member.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute)) as DisplayNameAttribute;
        return value?.DisplayName ?? expression.Member.Name ?? "";
    }
}
```

And here is how it is used:
`<NameLabel For="() => P.coor" />`
where P is the model and coor a member.

Note that this works for

```
[DisplayName("Coordinates")] [StringLength(1000)] public string coor { get; set; }
```

but not for

```
[Display (Name="Coordinates")] [StringLength(1000)] public string coor { get; set; }
```

I guess reflection can be used on the second attribute style too.